# notify-send icon: custom png

Tags: notifications

I'm trying to let a script send a couple of notifications with custom `png`s as icons. This could be easily put off as a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/351637/329400, but it isn't. In fact, I tried this exact solution, but the icon didn't display:

```
notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32/status/stock_lock-broken.png  summary test
```

[image: notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32/status/stock_lock-broken.png summary test]

I also made sure the image really exists in elementaryOS. It does:

```
xdg-open /usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32/status/stock_lock-broken.png
```

[image]

What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a bunch of bash scripts a while ago, and struggled with this issue as well. This is what I have going now, and it works:

[image]

This icon is located in ~/.local/share/icons. In this case it's a .svg file, but it will also work with other types:
 [image]
This is a python example:

[image]

And these are the results:

[image: bash notification]
[image: python notification]

The general idea is to put the icon file in the icons folder, maybe also reload the icon cache, and refer to that image in you commands by its name (using the full path will not work), without the extension.

So, your command should look like this:

```
notify-send -i stock_lock-broken  summary test
```

[image]

Comment: So there seems to be no way to simply specify a file in a random location?

Comment: There was a short discussiin about this, and it seems that, at least for now, in elementary os, notify-send does not accept full paths... https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1511217

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

Place icons in:

```
~/.local/share/icons/image.png
```

OR

```
/usr/share/icons/image.png
```

and use them with:

```
-i image
```

OR

```
--icon=image
```

Do not add extension to image name in the command flag, just image name.

example:

```
notify-send --icon=razer -a 'Razer Raiju TE (xboxdrv)' --urgency=normal --expire-time=2000 'Microsoft X-Box 360 pad' "Removed"
```

OR

```
notify-send -icon razer -a 'Razer Raiju TE (xboxdrv)' --urgency=normal --expire-time=2000 'Microsoft X-Box 360 pad' "Removed"
```